# Signing and Capabilities in Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, certificate, identifier

Xcode New User here.  Thank you for taking the time.

I have downloaded an Xcode build file and I'm trying to compile it but I am getting the error " Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: OpaqueCam" is Xcode managed, but signing settings require a manually managed profile."

The Code I am trying to use is SwiftCamera.

I am a developer and requested a certificate in Keychain.  I then went to the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and created a new profile for iOS and imported my certificate.  I imported that certificate back into Keychain and tried to import it into Xcode but it the program wouldn't see the file (greyed out) so I exported it from Keychain and found it in my \Library and copied it my desktop.

I was able to import it into Xcode and when I compiled, I got the error for a "manually managed profile"

1. I tried creating a provisioning profile on my computer
2. I tried creating a certificate in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and importing the provisioning profile from step 1
3. I loaded the certificate in my Xcode
4. I exported the certificate
5. I reimported the certificate into Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Download the code and open the project in Xcode.
2. Edit the app target and switch to Signing and Capabilities. Change the Team to yourself (personal team).
3. Xcode complains that the app identifier is not available. Change it to something unique to you. For example, I changed it to `com.neuburg.matt.SwiftCamera`. Click Try Again.
4. There is no step four.

You'll notice that I left the "Automatically manage signing" checkmark checked.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It installs with no problem now.